# How to find the largest repeating string with overlap in a line

Tags: regex, perl

I have a series of lines such as

```
my $string = "home test results results-apr-25 results-apr-251.csv";
@str = $string =~ /(\w+)\1+/i;
print "@str";
```

How do I find the largest repeating string with overlap which are separated by whitespace?
In this case I'm looking for the output :

```
results-apr-25
```

Comment: Something like this [`~(\S+)(?=.*?\1)~gs`](http://regex101.com/r/zR9aH7), you only need to figure out how to get the longest string from the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need the [`String::LCSS_XS`](https://metacpan.org/module/String%3a%3aLCSS_XS) which calculates Longest Common SubStrings. Don't try it's Perl-only twin brother [`String::LCSS`](https://metacpan.org/module/String%3a%3aLCSS) because there are bugs in that one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use String::LCSS_XS;
*lcss = \&String::LCSS_XS::lcss; # Manual import of `lcss`

my $var = 'home test results results-apr-25 results-apr-251.csv';
my @words = split ' ', $var;

my $longest;
my ($first, $second);

for my $i (0 .. $#words) {
  for my $j ($i + 1 .. $#words) {
    my $lcss = lcss(@words[$i,$j]);
    unless ($longest and length $lcss <= length $longest) {
      $longest = $lcss;
      ($first, $second) = @words[$i,$j];
    }
  }
}

printf qq{Longest common substring is "%s" between "%s" and "%s"\n}, $longest, $first, $second;
```

**output**

```
Longest common substring is "results-apr-25" between "results-apr-25" and "results-apr-251.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $var = "home test results results-apr-25 results-apr-251.csv";
my @str = split " ", $var;
my %h;
my $last = pop @str;

while (my $curr = pop @str ) {
        if(($curr =~/^$last/) || $last=~/^$curr/) {
                $h{length($curr)}= $curr ;
        }
        $last = $curr;
}

my $max_key = max(keys %h);
print $h{$max_key},"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it without a loop, you will need the `/g` regex modifier.

This will get you all the repeating string:

```
my @str = $string =~ /(\S+)(?=\s\1)/ig;
```

I have replaced `\w` with `\S` (in your example, `\w` doesn't match `-`), and used a look-ahead: `(?=\s\1)` means match something that is before `\s\1`, without matching `\s\1` itself—this is required to make sure that the next match attempt starts after the *first* string, not after the second.

Then, it is simply a matter of extracting the longest string from `@str`:

```
my $longest = (sort { length $b <=> length $a } @str)[0];
```

(Do note that this is a legible but far from being the most efficient way of finding the longest value, but this is the subject of [a different question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182010/the-fastest-way-execution-time-to-find-the-longest-element-in-an-list))

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my $var = "home test results results-apr-25 results-apr-251.csv";
my $l = length $var;
for (my $i=int($l/2); $i; $i--) {
    if ($var =~ /(\S{$i}).*\1/) {
        say "found: $1";
        last;
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
found:  results-apr-25
```