# Printing longest seq in an array using perl

Tags: perl

I have an array with sequences as shown below in it

```
my @a = qw(AAAA CGTGATG CGTGATTTGG);
```

I want to print out the sequence which is longest in the length using perl.
So output should be

```
CGTGATTTGG

#!/usr/bin/perl-w
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw( min max );

my %hash = ();
my @a = qw(AAAA CGTGATG CGTGATTTGG);

foreach(@a){
    print join("\t",$_,length($_)),"\n";
}
```

Which prints out

```
AAAA    4
CGTGATG 7
CGTGATTTGG  10
```

I just want to print the seq with the longest string that is 10

How can I do it

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that returns the first of the longest strings:

```
use List::Util qw( reduce );

my $longest = reduce { length($a) >= length($b) ? $a : $b } @a;
```

A simple solution that returns the all of the longest strings:

```
use List::Util qw( max );

my $max_len = max map { length($_) } @a;
my @longests = grep { length($_) == $max_len } @a;
```

Comment: This is the best answer for this specific question because strictly taking the longest sequence will lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fastest from the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182010/the-fastest-way-execution-time-to-find-the-longest-element-in-an-list) on this topic:

```
sub longest {
    my $max = -1;
    my $max_ref;
    for (@_) {
        if (length > $max) {  # no temp variable, length() twice is faster
            $max = length;
            $max_ref = \$_;   # avoid any copying
        }
    }
    $$max_ref
}
```

Comment: Note that this only finds one of the longest (the first one)

Comment: The OP stated: **"I just want to print the seq with the longest string"** This does that.

Comment: Again, only if there's only one string that's longest. If there's more than one sing tied for longest, it returns **one of the longest** instead.

Comment: I'm not saying your solution is wrong; I'm just making a note of how it behaves in the situation the OP forgot to cover.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map  { [$_, length($_)] }
             qw(AAAA CGTGATG CGTGATTTGG);

say $sorted[-1];
say pop(@sorted);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that ST helps here. It only helps if time it takes to find the length of a string the second time is longer than the time it takes to do `->[1]` (and that's not even counting ST's overhead). It might actually make things slower.

Comment: This solution doesn't scale well. It's O(N log N), while there exists an O(N) solution.